# Assembly negation in msp430

Tags: assembly, twos-complement, msp430, negate

I have the following versions of negating some integer value (in R12) in assembly in msp430 :

```
inv R12
inc R12
```

this is according to the manual and I think this will work the same?

```
inv R12
add #1, R12
```

But will this work and why not? :

```
sub #1, R12
inv R12
```

Still new to this and thank you for any help!

Comment: seems to work (except overflow cases)

Comment: Did you check the corner cases, like `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INC dst` is emulated with `ADD #1, dst`, so the first two versions are exactly the same.

As for the third version: In the two's complement representation, inverting all bits computes the negative minus one, so you are computing (−*x* − 1) + 1 or −(*x* + 1) + 1, which is indeed the same.

And if you want a more practical demonstration, just use brute force:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 0x10000; i++) {
        uint16_t input = i;
        uint16_t output1 = (~input) + 1;
        uint16_t output2 = ~(input - 1);
        assert(output1 == output2);
    }
    puts("it works!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the output the same even considering the alu flags output?

Comment: @Damiano That would be a different question. (Which can be answered with the manual.)